# Using advancedSyntax in Algolia Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algolia

I have Algolia search installed and working in my rails app. I want to set the [advancedSyntax](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#advancedsyntax) option to true for my indexed model. This is what I've tried in the model:

```
algoliasearch if: :approved?, per_environment: true do
  attribute :title, :location, :description, :posted_at, :id

  attributesToIndex ['title', 'description', 'location']


  attribute :posted_at_i do
    posted_at.to_i
  end

  customRanking ['desc(posted_at_i)']

  advancedSyntax true
end
```

And I get this error:

```
undefined method `advancedSyntax' for #<AlgoliaSearch::IndexSettings:0x0055955e3ca548>
```

I can't find advice that shows how to set this option in the rails model. Can it be done? and if so how?

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a missing feature of the Rails integration. [Here](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails/commit/89c40a2ea6e5678ece7f7afb111a3eafff066fd5) is the commit fixing it. It's part of the `1.15.1` version.